# UID for set flag and barrier commands in arcobjects .net

Tags: arcobjects

I have found below UID to add a flag and barrier.

Flag and Barrier Tools : {C86085FD-D8D9-11D2-9F4F-00C04F6BDF0E}

But nothing is executed when using this UID. I would need to know the UIDs for junction flag, junction barrier, edge flag and edge barrier to invoke them from my application developing using arcobjects .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all of the UID's [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#858a508c-b771-467c-81e6-c6aa72d88f9c.htm).

In your case here are the GUID's you are looking for:

Junction Flag: {11B02B2F-D8E7-11D2-9F4F-00C04F6BDF0E}
Junction Barrier: {26C85979-D8E7-11D2-9F4F-00C04F6BDF0E}
Edge Flag: {0768070F-D8E7-11D2-9F4F-00C04F6BDF0E}
Edge Barrier: I could not find this, the one you are looking for may have a different name.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working.but i con't find the Edge barrier UID .Any other option to get Edge barrier UID?.